# Couchbase: Is it possible to have stale cold cache?

Tags: caching, couchbase

We are considering to use Couchbase as persistent cache layer. Since Couchbase writes cache items to memory first and syncs to disk asynchronously, one concern we have is crash consistency. If some cache item were updated in memory and Couchbase crashes before committing them to disk, those items will be stale when Couchbase restarts.

My question is:

- Will Couchbase detect and report those items are stale? If so, we can just discard those items since they are cache.
- Is there any other Couchbase-specific ways to deal with the stale cache problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there would be a way to detect if a document is stale, since (in your scenario) they weren't written to disk before a crash.

However, you can specify [durability requirements](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/dotnet-2.2/persistto.html) when creating a document. By default, a write is considered successful if it makes it into memory. You can add additional constraints like "PersistTo" (the document must be persisted to N number of nodes before the write is considered successful).